# call a method of a class in another method in that same class in python

Tags: python-3.x

how i can call a method in a class to another method in that same class in python3?

```
class foo
     def method1(self):
          return something 
     def method2(self):
          print(method1())
```

my actual code is :

```
class MSD:
    #it find maximum shared divisible of two number
    def __init__(self,firstNumber1,secondNumber1):
        self.firstNumber=firstNumber1
        self.secondNumber=secondNumber1
    def alldivisible(self):
        __all_divisible_list1 =[]
        __all_divisible_list2=[]
        for i in range(1, int(self.firstNumber)+1):
            if self.firstNumber % i == 0:
                __all_divisible_list1 = __all_divisible_list1+[i]
        for i in range(1, int(self.secondNumber)+1):
            if self.secondNumber % i == 0:
                __all_divisible_list2 = __all_divisible_list2 + [i]
            common_divisible_list = set(__all_divisible_list1) & set(__all_divisible_list2)
        return max(common_divisible_list)
class fractionStuff:
    def __init__(self,first_fraction1,secound_fraction1):
        self.firstFraction=((first_fraction1)).split("/")
        self.secoundFraction=((secound_fraction1).split('/'))
    def sumCalculate(self):
        print()#HERE
```

here i wanna find divisible of two numbers which i wanna define.
what i must do? i need write my function out of class?

Comment: http://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Comment: sorry. stupid question. i defined seperated class by myself .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `self` reference is required:

```
class Foo:
     def method1(self):
          return "something"

     def method2(self):
          print(self.method1())
```

Comment: datas are diffrent . not class input argumans . a part of them .

Answer (score 1):

All access to the members of a class is through the `self` parameter. That's not just attribute variables, it's methods as well.

```
print(self.method1())
```

Comment: can i call like print(self.method1(a,b))? which a ,b wasnt in __init__?

Comment: @SaebMolaee the code you show in your question doesn't have arguments. What are you talking about?

Comment: sorry. stupid question. i defined seperated class by myself .